# Seasonal time series prediction formula

Tags: time-series

I've got this prediction problem for daily data across several years. My data has both yearly and weekly seasonality. It's also stationary.

I tried using the following recurrence:(which I just came up with, from nowhere if you like) x<sub>n</sub> = 1/4(x<sub>n-738</sub> + x<sub>n-364</sub> + x<sub>n-7</sub> + 1/6(x<sub>n-1</sub>+x<sub>n-2</sub>+x<sub>n-3</sub>+x<sub>n-4</sub>+x<sub>n-5</sub>+x<sub>n-6</sub>)

Basically, I am taking into consideration some of the previous days in the week before the day I am trying to predict and also the corresponding day a year and two years earlier. I am doing an average over them.

I got the following histogram of residuals:
[image]

Why or Why not would such a formula be a good idea and can I improve this FOR example by adding some terms sampled from a distribution or in another way? Thanks!

Comment: Stationary series can't be seasonal. Please double check your data.

Comment: Yeah, I didn’t realise that stationarity had such a technical definition...I didn’t really check the stationarity But maybe people could help me regardless of that condition? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the recurrence formula you've come up with, you seem to be trying to reinvent an [Auto-Regressive model AR(p)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model), which is essentially any model of the form:

$X_n = a_1 X_{n-1} + a_2 X_{n-2} + a_3 X_{n-3} + ... a_p X_{n-p}$.

Although your intuition is correct and your approach is on the correct path, there is a more systematic way of arriving at the same type of model that you are trying to achieve, using [ARIMA](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/8) and [Seasonal ARIMA](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/8/9) models.

Comment: Hi Alex and thanks for the answer!
I tried using ARIMA and Seasonal ARIMA but the problem is that ARIMA cannot capture double seasonality, so I tried to come up with something myself. Any idea how one could find the optimal a1,...,ap ? Optimal wrt to mean squared residual error for example

Comment: @SorinTirc I don't know of any ARIMA model that can capture multiple seasonalities (In theory a really high order ARIMA model could, but in practice that would lead to bad results). You should try TBATs or Facebook Prophet - but those models use completely different approaches from the auto-regressive models.